# Cannot deserialize protobuf

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am having trouble de-serializing a protobuf. I am confident that it is serialized properly, as serialization works in all other cases.

Here's a simplified proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Request {
  oneof request {
    LoginRequest login = 1;
    SyncRequest sync = 2;
    PushRequest push = 3;
  }
}

message LoginRequest {
  string username = 1;
  string password = 2;
}

message SyncRequest {
}

message PushRequest {
  message Item {
    int64 id = 1;
    string value = 2;
    string date = 3;
  }

  repeated Item items = 1;
}
```

I read and de-serialize the protobuf in the `doPost` method of an `HttpServlet`:

```java
@Override
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest httpRequest, final HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
  final BufferedReader reader = httpRequest.getReader();
  final byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(reader, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

  final Request request;

  try {
    // TODO: Read from input stream directly.
    request = Request.parseFrom(buffer);
  } catch(final Exception e) {
    throw new ServletException("Failed to deserialize request body.", e);
  }

  // Never reaches this line.
  // ...
}
```

I get the following error:

```
11:44:23.199 [qtp1165303897-24] WARN  o.e.j.ee10.servlet.ServletChannel - handleException /api com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
```

If I sent `Request.login` or `Request.sync`, it successfully de-serializes. The error only occurs for `Request.push`.

Comment: Something tells me that BufferedReader garbles the input. Try to use directly `HttpServletRequest.getInputStream()`.

Comment: @gudok Thanks for your quick response. I will try and let you know. It would be weird if it works though, since it works for the other two.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be weird at all. `BufferedReader` is for *text* data - protobuf serialization is arbitrary *binary* data. You're converting the request from binary data to text again and expecting to get the same original bytes out... that's *never* a good idea, unless you know the original data is genuinely text.

Comment: Yup it works. `HttpServletRequest#getReader()` reads the body as characters.

Comment: I guess however protobuf serializes repeated cannot be read as character data. If you want to post your response as an answer, I'll mark it.